# pip3 is broken and not installing packages anymore

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I used to install python3 packages via pip3, however since today it is not working anymore. 
Checking my history gives me this:

```
lkjhr@X1-Carbon-6:~$ history | grep pip3
  562  pip3 install matplotlib
 1029  pip3 install flask
```

However, since today I noticed that it is not working at all, look like I broke it or something?

```
lkjh@X1-Carbon-6:~$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

lkjh@X1-Carbon-6:~$ pip3 --version
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip

lkjh@X1-Carbon-6:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libvncserver1 linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-135
  linux-headers-4.4.0-135-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-135-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-135-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

lkjh@X1-Carbon-6:~$ python3-pip install bokeh
python3-pip: command not found

lkjh@X1-Carbon-6:~$ pip3 install bokeh
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

What could go wrong? (surprised)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As a temporary workaround, try `python3 -m pip install bokeh`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the details on your OS?

Comment: `dpkg --listfiles python3-pip | grep bin/pip`

Comment: dont know how to update the question, for OS I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ dpkg --listfiles python3-pip | grep bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip3
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ sudo /usr/bin/pip3 install brunel
sudo: /usr/bin/pip3: command not found
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ /usr/bin/pip3
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory

Comment: pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ python3  -m pip3 install brunel
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3

Comment: this page helped to fix my problem and I got back my running pip3.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/778052/installing-pip3-for-python3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-using-a-proxy